# How do I disable network interfaces from loading at boot without Network Manager?

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface

The machine I'm using has 4 network interfaces, only one of which is currently being used (the other 3 are not plugged in at all). Currently when the machine is restarted it is delayed by a few minutes trying to bring up interfaces 2-4. This is a pretty significant annoyance because this machine is restarted very often.

Running dmesg I see that:

```
[15] IPv6 ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[57] IPv6 ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[98] IPv6 ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth3: link is not ready
[140] ...
```

seeing as these interfaces are not being used and taking up a lot of time I'd like to simply disable them from trying to start up, but I would be open to other options that would reduce the time wasted on these interfaces.

I've checked `/etc/sysctrl.conf` and IPv6 is disabled, so I wouldn't think it to try IPv6.

In the network-scripts directory I created scripts for interface 2-4 that just contain their interface name and `ONBOOT=no`.

Also I've looked in `/sys/class/net/ethX/device/power/control` for each interface, all of them contain "on" so I tried:

```
echo off > /sys/class/net/ethX/device/power/control
```

But I get `write error: Invalid argument`, whereas echoing `on` works fine. I haven't been able to find a reference for changing this file but I feel as though turning the interfaces off entirely would be a little extreme.

I do not have network manager installed and would prefer to keep it that way if at all possible (prefer configuration over throwing more packages at the problem).

---

I have since moved on from this issue, however for the sake of others that might experience this I'll mention that the fact `dmesg` is reporting these long waits suggests that the kernel is what's trying to enable these interfaces. So possibly kernel parameters would be an avenue to pursue, or it might just be a kernel bug. Configurations in Linux itself is unlikely to solve the problem, either the `grub` config or changes to the kernel itself might do it.

---

**UPDATE**

The self-answer I posted I actually did get a chance to test, but it didn't work out. However, posting what I tried.

Noticing that the messages from `dmesg` suggests the kernel is performing the action I looked through the kernel paramaters documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt

I found there is an option for configuring IPv6 on interfaces: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ipv6.txt.

---

The page outlines the following kernel options:

`disable=[01]` 0 loads the IPv6 module (default), 1 does not load the IPv6 module

`autoconf=[01]` 0 disables IPv6 auto-configuration on all interfaces, 1 enables auto-configuration on all interfaces (default)

`disable_ipv6=[01]` 0 enables IPv6 on all interfaces (default), 1 disables IPv6 on all interfaces

However, none of these options addressed the issue.

Comment: Look in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface name>` - is there an `ONBOOT=` line?

Comment: @John sorry I should have also mentioned, the interfaces previously didn't have a network script, so I created mostly blank ones for each that state only the interface and ONBOOT=no

Comment: On debian based removal of the auto in the ‘/etc/network/interfaces’ will prevent the nic from coming on line at boot time.

Comment: @jc__ That wont stop `grub` from trying to start it, which I'm pretty sure was the source of the problem.

Comment: okay? All of the debug info and work done in the question is in the OS, after grub. `dmesg` and `sysctrl`.

Comment: How long is the delay between grub, boot loader, and the first message from the OS, linux. Once you get some message like `Loading, please wait.` or something like `/dev/sda1: clean...` grub has terminated and passes control to the OS. To prevent the OS from setting up the nic, change the network config. What OS are you using?

Comment: I dont use centos but it looks like `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` key named `ONBOOT=` could help.

Comment: @jc__ I misspoke, I don't think that `grub` is trying to start the interfaces, rather that the kernel is trying to start them (`dmesg` prints kernel messages) so I expect the fix would be done using `grub` (as I mention in the question). The OS is RHEL 7, boot time takes between 5-10 minutes and the `ONBOOT=no` is set as the question states.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/181254/how-do-you-boot-linux-with-networking-disabled

Comment: @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功 The idea with this problem was that interface 1 is still in use. Disabling all networking is definitely too heavy handed.

Comment: @Centimane not implying duplication, only relatedness ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could add these lines in your /etc/rc.local :

```
ip link set dev "eth1" down
ip link set dev "eth2" down
ip link set dev "eth3" down
```

Unless it is a too basic or static solution...

Comment: Would that stop them from starting at boot time? That seems like it would simply try to stop the interfaces at a later point, after they have already timed out. If I do "ip link show dev eth1" it reports its state is already "DOWN".

Comment: Ok, it's probably a wrong answer, so. Have you also looked into BIOS settings ? Sometimes you can choose which interfaces you want to be activated...

Comment: I may be able to disable the other interfaces through the BIOS, but that's akin to removing them from the machine, that's a little more extreme than I'd like to go. I'm trying to find a config solution to the interfaces starting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying problem and, I'm not an expert, but searching inside the config files, found the solution on my Devuan actual lastest version:

- Edit file `/etc/init.d/networking`
- There's a line:

  ```
  CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=
  ```

  Set this to `no`

Answer (score 0):

To selectively disable certain network interfaces from starting at boot, without NetworkManager, in RHEL or related distribution, edit the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface>` file that corresponds to the interface you wish to disable, and change the line `ONBOOT="yes"` to `ONBOOT="no"`.